# HTTP Error: curl ERROR: 27: SSL: couldn't create a context in Heroku

Tags: php, web-services, ssl, curl, heroku

I have a PHP website that calls a web service via SOAP. It is calling the WS using nusoap.

It's working very well on my local machine and another server, but in Heroku, the following exception was thrown:

> HTTP Error: cURL ERROR: 27: SSL: couldn't create a context: error:140A90C4:SSL 
>     routines:SSL_CTX_new:null ssl method passed
>     url: https://xxx/yyy.Services
>     content_type:

The code is:

```
// Primeiro Try
$obClient = new nusoap_client ( $url_webservice, 'wsdl' );
$obClient->setCurlOption(CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 4);

$erro = $obClient->getError ();
if ($erro) {
    throw new Exception ( "Erro ao conectar", 9999 );
}

$retorno = $obClient->call ( $funcao_chamada, $parametros );

if ($obClient->fault != '') {
    $error = $obClient->error_str;
    throw new Exception ( utf8_encode ( $error ), 9997 );

} 

$erro = $obClient->getError ();
if ($erro) {
    $error = $obClient->error_str;
    throw new Exception ( utf8_encode ( $error ), 9998 );
} 

 return $retorno;
}
```

What it's happening?

Answer (score 6):

I 'm using the nusoap.php, and I was call the method setCurlOption passing the follow params:

setCurlOption(CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 4)

When I commented this line the problem was fixed.

Comment: Bravo, anyone knows why?

Comment: Universe is this way, and that is enough! :D

It was result of try and error